# Define height based on width using css

Tags: css

I need to set an element's height to be 2/3 of its width. I know I can do this using JS in something like `$(this).height($(this).width()/3*2)`

Can I do the same thing using straight CSS without pre-processors?

Comment: You could set the element to `height: 0;padding-bottom: 66.67%`, but then you'll have to absolutely-position any child content. Whether this is practical depends on what's inside the element.

Comment: @Blazemonger it acctually works exactly the way I needed. Thank you

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 1):

yep there is a popular hack for this

but now we have css variables/ custom properties, you can use that.
Not fully supported though

```css
.p{
  width: 60px;
}

.c {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150%;
}

/* advanced css custom properties */
.a {
  --width: 60px;
  width: var(--width);
  height: calc(var(--width)*1.5);
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
 
 <!-- hack using padding -->
 <div class="p">
    <div class="c">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  <!-- advanced css using custom properties/ css variables --> 
  <div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could set the element to `height: 0;padding-bottom: 66.67%`, but then you'll have to absolutely-position any child content. Whether this is practical depends on what's inside the element.